# How to pass an image to a function?

Tags: multithreading, function, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

Here is the code I used:

```
import threading
import cv2

def showimg(*a):
    cv2.imshow('img', a)
    cv2.waitKey(5)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def main():
    img = cv2.imread('tree.jpg')
    t = threading.Thread(target = showimg, args = (img) )
    t.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

A simple code, how to pass a color image into a function?

I am getting an error like:

```
TypeError: mat is not a numerical tuple
```

I can't get my head around it.

Q1: What am I missing?

Q2: Does color and gray image work same?

Answer (score 0):

I did not get why you were using `import thread` in the first place.

You can pass an image to a function relatively in a much easier way:

```
import cv2

def showimg(a):
    cv2.imshow('img', a)

img = cv2.imread('tree.jpg')
showimg(img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```